# Comparing two array of object javascript and remove values that are not equal

Tags: javascript

I have two array of objects.

```
e = [{uniqueId:'',active:'a',qId:10},{uniqueId:'',active:'a',qId:11}]
f = [{uniqueId:50,active:'a',qId:10},{uniqueId:51,active:'a',qId:11},{uniqueId:52,active:'a',qId:13}]
```

I want to compare these objects and my final result will be like

```
result = [{uniqueId:50,active:'a',qId:10},{uniqueId:51,active:'a',qId:11}]
```

I tried

```
let result = e.filter(o1 => f.some(o2 => o1.qId != o2.qId));
```

But am getting

```
[{uniqueId:50,active:'a',qId:10},{uniqueId:51,active:'a',qId:11},{uniqueId:52,active:'a',qId:13}]
```

How to achieve the desired output?

Comment: please add what you mean by "*... values that are not equal*"

Comment: Compare the two array of objects using 'qId', if qId is present in one object and not in the other, i don't want that object in result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if array `e` has the same `qId` value for filtering `f`.

```js
var e = [{ uniqueId: '', active: 'a', qId: 10 }, { uniqueId: '', active: 'a', qId: 11 }],
    f = [{ uniqueId: 50, active: 'a', qId: 10 }, { uniqueId: 51, active: 'a', qId: 11 }, { uniqueId: 52, active: 'a', qId: 13 }],
    result = f.filter(({ qId }) => e.some(o => o.qId === qId));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz; i am doing the same thing with the just one condition change about ```not equal to !== ``` but that is not working in my case. So is there any other method to work with the not equal to condition ? Check my live example over here: https://playcode.io/586815/

Comment: @aananddham, please ask a new question, if necessary. the comment section is not to answer another question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you should be filtering `f`, not `e`, because the `result` shows values from `f`, not from `e`.

For the least complexity, turn the `e` array's `qId`s into a `Set` for quick lookup first. (`Set`s have `O(1)` lookup time, compared to `O(N)` complexity for `.some`)

```js
const e = [{uniqueId:'',active:'a',qId:10},{uniqueId:'',active:'a',qId:11}]
const f = [{uniqueId:50,active:'a',qId:10},{uniqueId:51,active:'a',qId:11},{uniqueId:52,active:'a',qId:13}]

const qIds = new Set(e.map(({ qId }) => qId));
console.log(f.filter(({ qId }) => qIds.has(qId)));
```

Answer (score 2):

i hope you need to compare on qId..

```js
let e = [{uniqueId:'',active:'a',qId:10},{uniqueId:'',active:'a',qId:11}]
let f = [{uniqueId:50,active:'a',qId:10},{uniqueId:51,active:'a',qId:11},{uniqueId:52,active:'a',qId:13}]
let res = [];
f.forEach(fo => {
  e.forEach(eo => {
    if(fo.qId === eo.qId){
       res.push(fo)
    }
  })
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filter()` and `Array.some()` in combination to get that result:

```js
e = [{uniqueId:'',active:'a',qId:10},{uniqueId:'',active:'a',qId:11}]
f = [{uniqueId:50,active:'a',qId:10},{uniqueId:51,active:'a',qId:11},{uniqueId:52,active:'a',qId:13}];
var res = f.filter(fItem => e.some(({qId}) => fItem.qId === qId));
console.log(res);
```